# The number of non-singular $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with exactly $k$ non-zero entries

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, finite-fields

Suppose $M_{n}^{k}$ is the number of regular matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{F}_2)$, that have exactly $k$ non-zero entries. 
Is there some sort of formula to calculate $M_n^k$?

$$(k < n\;\lor\;k > n^2 - n + 1)\overset{\text{pigeonhole principle}}\implies M_n^k = 0$$

(in $1^{\text{st}}$ case we always have at least one zero row, in $2^{\text{nd}}$ case we always have at least two identical rows). 
If $k = n$, then all such regular matrices have to be permutation matrices. Thus $M_n^n = n!$. 
However, I do not know, how to deal with the situation, where $n < k < n^2 - n + 1$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: One more easy case: if $k=n+1$ then you must have a permutation matrix plus one more $1$ (which can be anywhere).  The permutation matrix is uniquely determined (all but one of the columns have only one $1$ and a permutation is determined by its values on all but one point) so that gives $n!(n^2-n)$ possibilities.

Comment: If $k=n+2$, there are $$n!(n^2-n)(n^2-n-2)/2$$ possibilities.

Comment: @san -  how did you get that formula for $k=n+2$?

Comment: Another case: if $k = n^2 - n + 1$, there are $n-1$ zeros and they must necessarily be on different columns and different rows (otherwise there are 2 columns or 2 rows with all $1$s).  So the $n-1$ zeros also define a permutation (of which one entry gets replaced by a $1$).  Thus $M \le n! \times n$.  For sufficiency: consider any subset of $c>1$ columns.  Since $c > 1$, at least $1$ row has exactly one $0$ in it.  Also, there exists a row with all $1$s in it.  These $2$ rows cannot simultaneously sum to $0$.  So any subset is independent and the matrix is non-singular.  So $M = n! \ n$.

Comment: If $k=n+2$, you can start with a permutation matrix $P$, i.e., $P_{i,j}=\delta_{j,\sigma(i)}$, where $\sigma$ is a permutation. Then you have to add two non-zero entries. 
So you have $\binom {n^2-n}{2}$ choices. But if one entry is $i,j$, you cannot choose the entry 
$\sigma^{-1}(j),\sigma(i)$ as the other entry, and this is the only exception, so you have $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$ invalid pairs. Then you have
$$
\binom {n^2-n}{2}-\frac{n^2-n}{2}=(n^2−n)(n^2−n−2)/2
$$
valid pairs, and so the total number of non-singular matrices is
$$
n!(n^2−n)(n^2−n−2)/2.
$$

Comment: It gets ugly very rapidly. If $k=n+3$ and you start from a permutation, you have to rule out adding the trhree additional 1's at $(i,j),(k,\sigma(i)),(\sigma^{-1}(j),\sigma(k))$, besides the previous restrictions.

Comment: I guess you already know that $\sum_k M_n^k = \prod_{q=0}^{n-1}(2^n - 2^q)$. Not sure it is useful for your concern, except maybe to check a particular solution

Comment: It might be useful : det(M) = 1 if and only if we can "include" (with a natural meaning) an odd number of permutations in M ; this is just a consequence of the determinant formula. In terms of permutations, you want to know when the number of permutations such that $\sigma(i) \in I_i$ for given sets $I_1, .. I_n$ is odd or not, or at least to count the odd ones. It might also be useful to consider the following problem : counting the invertible matrix which has exactly $\alpha_i$ nonzero termes in the $i-th$ column for all $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a way to generate the matrices : 
We start with a permutation matrix $P$. There are $n!$ permutations with each of them having $n$ non zero entries.

So now we are going to add $ E_1 $ such that $E_1$ equals zero everywhere except its $(i,j)$ entry. We want the sum to still be non-singular so $i$ and $j$ can take $n^2-n$ values in total. We can add a one to any entry that was previously zero.

If we want to add another matrix $E_2$ we have $n^2 - n -1$ possible entries for the non zero element. If we repeat the process $m$ times $Card(E_m)=n^2-(n+m-1)$.  We continue until $m$ verifies that $m=k-n  .$ And we have generated a non singular matrix with exactly $k$ non zero entries.

We can conclude that: $$M_k^n=(n!*(n^2-n)*(n^2-n-1)...*(n^2-k+1)).$$
We just multiplied the number of possibilites allowed at each step of the process. I'am not 100% sure so if anything seems out of touch please tell me. 
All this reasoning for $n<k<n^2 -n +1 $.

Comment: How do you reason that $i$ and $j$ can take $n^2-n$ values for the matrix to remain non-singular?

Comment: There aren't $n^2 - n - 1$ possibilities for $E_2$.  Without loss you can imagine the original permutation to be the identity matrix, and the $E_1$ to have its $1$ at $(0,1)$.  Then you cannot add another $1$ at $(1,0)$.  I _think_ this is the only prohibited spot, so $E_2$ has $n^2 - n - 2$ possibilities for the matrix to remain singular.  But I don't think this kind of logic generalizes easily beyond $E_2$...

Comment: The reasoning to justify that $i$ and $j$ can take $n^2-n$ values is that the permutation matrix contains $n$ non zero entries.  And $i$  and $ j$  can initialy take any $n^2$ value if we do not add any constraint but we don't want to add a 1 to another 1 because if would become a 0 in the sum of the matrices. So how many possibilities remain ? Well the initial number of positions minus the number of positions already filled with a non zero entry. Did you find this helpful ?

Comment: do you understand what "non-singular" mean?

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \leadsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \leadsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ which is singular. Similar constructions can be made for bigger matrix dimensions $n$.